# Have you seen this bug? How in the world to start finding it?

Tags: ogre3d

I was minding my own business, working on code completely unrelated to the shaders, and all of a sudden my Ogre3D application crashes on launch.

If I launch and select DX9, the last lines of the log are:

```
Hydrax Initialization
[Hydrax] Hydrax created.
[Hydrax] HydraxDemo.hdx loaded.
```

If I launch and select OpenGL, it gets past Hydrax, and crashes on SkyX:

```
GLSL compiling: SkyX_Skydome_VP_GLSL
GLSL compiled:
GLSL compiling: SkyX_Skydome_STARFIELD_LDR_FP_GLSL
GLSL compiled: Vertex Program:SkyX_Skydome_VP_GLSL Fragment Program:SkyX_Skydome_STARFIELD_LDR_FP_GLSL GLSL link result :
```

I have tried these things without success:
1. revert today's (unrelated) source changes
2. rebuild the whole system
3. reboot

It seems to be crashing within RenderSystem_GL.dll

I changed nothing, but I get a different result.  How to go about finding out what went wrong?

Comment: Is there any chance you've modified Ogre config files, so it loads plugins from different directory? Does is break in Debug and Release?

Comment: Thanks for the idea.  That was not it this time, but it sure is useful to know many different ways that things can go wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Never code faster than you can debug... or something like that.  Should I review all the avenues investigated, or just jump to the solution? Skip ahead if you just want the solution.

I made a complete backup two days earlier, so I ran the application from the backup drive.  It worked fine.  Something in the code or the data (or the machine) had changed, but the old version ran fine on the same machine, so windows updates and hardware funkiness was eliminated.

Next I tried running the old application within the new data directories, and it crashed, because of a difference in data structures between the two builds.  No information from that test.

Then I tried running the new application within the old data directoies, and it crashed in the same spot described above.  That suggests the bug is within the executable, even if my edits can't possibly be related to the shader.

Next I looked at the *.DLL files... all 42 of them.  No difference.

Then I looked at the forty *.O files.  Only two had been changed.  Three source files were different.  I put the originals back in, rebuilt all the *.O files, linked, and it worked!!

SOLUTION:
Suddenly I did not need to dig deeper.  I recalled my last change to the GUI.  I had extra lines on my 2D overlay, and I had removed the constructor for a line that was no longer needed.  However, I did not remove the corresponding periodic update to that line.  Not even one frame was displayed before the system tried to update the NULL pointer, and CRASH !!

The shader just happened to be the last module to print to the log before the crash.  The error was not in a DLL-- just in my source, and at my last edit as well.  Since I knew I had done nothing with the shader, I got stuck thinking deeper and deeper about how the shader could have been broken by any of my minor edits.  it became hard to imagine what could cause it.  Usually the bug is in the last thing or two that I did, and this was no exception to the rule.